# How to dynamically display formatted text in TextBlock wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have some text in a resx file that I need to display in a TextBlock. This text will have **Bold** areas that I will have to show in **Bold**.  What is the best way to maintain **Bold** areas when the text changes? I cannot do inline from code behind because the text in resx file can change.  WPF vb.net application.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx)**:

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding BoldTextProperty}" />
    <Run FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding ItalicandRedColorTextProperty}" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

If you are not using binding, assign the text directly to the **Text** property.

**You can also bind the other properties:**

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="{Binding Weight}"
         FontSize="{Binding Size}"
         Text="{Binding LineOne}" />
    <Run FontStyle="{Binding Style}"
         Foreground="Binding Colour}"
         Text="{Binding LineTwo}" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

You can bind through converters if you have bold as a boolean (say).

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some changes.  I removed the text from resx file and put it into a .txt file instead. I created a .txt file for each body under a header and hard coded the headers.  Using Inline from code behind I controlled what goes in the header and what goes under it as the body.  This way body of the text can be changed in the .txt files and code will stay the same.